# min and max value in 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, java-2d

I want to output max and min value of 2d array. Max works well, but min always outputs zero even when theres no zeros in array.I set `Math.random()` to 99 to prevent smaller chance to get zero in array for this example. Heres full code:

```
public class e {

public static void main(String[] args)   {

    int a[][] = new int [5][5];
    int l = a[0][0];
    int m = a[0][0];
    int i,j,r,k;


    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)                   // 
        for(j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){           // 2d array random number generator
            a[i][j] =(int)(Math.random()*99); //
         }
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){               //
        for(j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)         //
                                           // create 2d array and output it
    System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");      //   
    System.out.println();                  //

}
    System.out.println("\t"); 
        for(r=0;r<a.length;r++){           //
            for(k=0;k<a.length;k++)        //
                if(a[r][k] < m){           // finds a min value
                    m = a[r][k];           //

            }
        }

    System.out.println("\t");               // 
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){            //
            for(j=0;j<a.length;j++)         // finds a max value
                if(a[i][j] > l){            //
                    l = a[i][j];            //

            }
        }
    System.out.println("min value is " + m); //outputs min value
    System.out.println("max value is " + l); // outputs max value
            }
       }
```

Comment: There may be no zeros in your array after you change the values to random numbers, but there certainly are zeros in your array when you initialize `m` with `int m = a[0][0];` which is why `m` remains `0` when your print it.

Comment: @jedwards it wasn't the problem, in `m = a[0][0]` it just define first integer in 2d array

Comment: it absolutely was the problem.  When you initialize `m` there, `a[0][0]` is 0.  So when you run your loop, you never find a value less than `m`, so `m` remains unchanged as 0.  By using Andy's solution (which is correct), you're reassigning `m` to be an arbitrary value in the matrix, allowing your loop to correctly find the minimum value.

Comment: @jedwards ou  now  I get it, my mistake, now I understand it, thank you for your response and for explaining to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way you choose the random values in `a`, there will be no value less than zero - but there is also no guarantee that any of the values will be exactly zero. However, you initialize `m` to be zero, since that is the default value of the array elements; nothing can be smaller than this, so the answer is always zero.

You should initialize your `m = a[0][0]` immediately before you start the outer for loop in the block labelled "finds a min value", i.e.

```
    m = a[0][0];
    for(r=0;r<a.length;r++){           //
        for(k=0;k<a.length;k++)        //
            if(a[r][k] < m){           // finds a min value
                m = a[r][k];           //

        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can set `m = Integer.MAX_VALUE` (and `l = Integer.MIN_VALUE`), since these are guaranteed to have values smaller and larger than them, respectively.

Comment: you were right, but can you explane me why it work with max, but didn't work for min?

Comment: Your random values are in the range 0..99, so even in the highly unlikely event that all of the random values are set to zero, the initial value of `l` is less than or equal to the actual maximum.