# How to set the value of a contours in a gray image to the highest value of this contours?

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I want to equalize all the value of a contour to its highest value of this contour, for better understanding please look at the images below:
[image: Contours]

Here look to the first contour which has the max value 200, after the process, all the area became the same as the highest value, and also the second one, which has the highest value 255, after the process all the area of this contour became the same.

Is there any easy and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and it's fairly easy in opencv with thresholding. Here's the code in Python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread(your_input_image_path)

max_value=np.max(img)

#thresholding : setting every pixel in img above 1 to max_value
_,th=cv2.threshold(img,1,max_value,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imwrite(your_output_image_path,th)
```

Input : 
[image: input]

Output :
[image: output]

This works for both your images, would need a little tweaking if your background is not always black, or is you want to do it on a specific object (I'm a little set back by your use of the word contour). If so, then you need to use `findContours` or such to first get the boundaries of your object and then threshold only that part of the image using a mask.
But if your images are always one object on a black backgroun, then this code works.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what is `np.max()` I am using OpenCV in Java,

Comment: maximum of a (here)2D array.

Comment: I am just looking for something to get the max value, but how to do it in Java

Comment: Not a Java coder, and it seems a bit more complicated than with Python, but for example in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452190/min-and-max-value-in-2d-array-java, this guy does it with a double for loop

Comment: I have find how get the max value, minMaxLoc() Opencv builtin function.